# Can a Qooxdoo Desktop root be set to a HTML DIV?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'd like to have my Qooxdoo Desktop app operate inside of a specific DIV, rather than the document root. Is it possible, and if so, where would I change the setting/s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [the inline application](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/api/#qx.application.Inline) is meant for. The demo browser contains [a simple demo](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.1/demobrowser/index.html#root~Inline_Window.html) which just opens a window.

You can use it for a complete application. If the content is mixed, you may need to take care of effects that you can see when resizing the demo window (in this case selecting the text).